# Using mysql between for date overlap for booking purpose

Tags: mysql, date, between

I am using mysql `BETWEEN` statement to find the overlap between the dates.It returns quite good results. But still there are few problems that I hope can be resolved.Thanks.

This is my database for testing

```
booking_id |venue_id |startdate   | enddate
1001       |3        | 2017-07-21 |2017-07-23
```

This is my query; my concept is either one of the date hit the query so it will return true.so i am using OR to test them.

```
SELECT * FROM `booking` WHERE ('user_inputdate_1' BETWEEN startdate AND enddate) OR ('user_inputdate_2' BETWEEN startdate AND enddate)'
```

My testing result

```
user_inputdate_1  user_inputdate_2  Result 
2017-07-19        2017-07-23         true 
2017-07-22        2017-07-24         true 
2017-07-21        2017-07-24         true 
2017-07-20        2017-07-24         false => this is the problem (it should be true)
```

PS: If there any other ways to solve this, I will accept them. I have been trying lot of queries but they did not work for me.

Lastly,thanks for all your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given input dates:

`2017-07-20` & `2017-07-24`

neither `start date` is greater or equal to `2017-07-21` and `end date` is also not less than or equal to `2017-07-23`. That's why the result `false`, which is right.

So instead of `between`, try:

```
WHERE 'user_inputdate_1' <= `enddate`
OR 'user_inputdate_2' => `startdate`;
```

Edited: Missing equals to `=` sign

Comment: it should be add equal sign for both.anyways thank for the solution,it nw work for me!                                                                                        
WHERE 'user_inputdate_1' <= `enddate`
OR 'user_inputdate_2' >= `startdate`;